# Unpivot Data in Power BI (Transform Table Horizontal to Vertical)

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, data-cleaning, m

I have an Excel file that looks like this:

| Component | Italy | Austria | Germany |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Not active | Not active | Active |
| Two | Active | Not active | Active |
| Three | Active | Not active | Not active |
| Four | Not active | Active | Active |

I wanted to create a normalized table to use in Power BI,

| Component | Country | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Italy | Not active |
| One | Austria | Not active |
| One | Germany | Active |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Four | Italy | Not active |
| Four | Austria | Active |
| Four | Germany | Active |

Usually the normalized tables are the one I use in Power BI, my question is:

- is there any way to transform the data source in Power BI to have the normalized structure? or
- is it possible to handle the original format in Power BI in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely reshape this data. When importing in PQ, highlight the Component column and then on the transform tab of the ribbon, select unpivot other columns. You can then rename the columns as you see fit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the exact answer.